# Number of points on an elliptic curve over $F_{p^n}$

Tags: elliptic-curves

$E$ is an elliptic curve with non-split multiplicative reduction at prime $p$. I'm trying to find the number of points $E$ over $F_{p^n}$.

I know that when I remove the singularity, the rest is a group isomorphic to the kernel of the norm map from the quadratic extension of the base, t.i. includes $p^n+1$ elements (if I'm not mistaken). Plus one singular point and the answer is $p^n+2$.

But I found that this number of points depends whether n is odd or even.
Why it is so?

Comment: Relevant MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98466/how-many-points-are-there-on-an-elliptic-curve-reduced-at-a-bad-prime

Comment: Thanks! But there isn't answer why the number depends on evenness of n

Comment: From zeta-function I found that for odd n the answer is p^n+2, and for even - p^n. The second one seems strange. Why it is so?